# Group by in Orange, Data mining

Tags: pandas, data-mining, orange

I have a dataset for a supermarket, each transaction containing an item is represented in a row. So, if transaction 1 contained milk, bread and coffee, the items are on a separate row and the attribute transaction occurs three times. What I want to do is to group transactions by item so that all the items are concatenated in one column. Then lastly apply association rules and separate each item in a column as an itemset. Is this even possible in Orange?

Worth mentioning, I managed to do this in RapidMiner easily with the same dataset. I used the Aggregate operator, concatenated the item attributes and then grouped by transactions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you wish to aggregate columns, not rows. If so, there's Aggregate Columns widget available for that. To perform Group by on rows, there's currently Pivot, which has a Group by output. We are working on a separate Group by widget, which should be available in the next release.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I've looked at both widgets and they're producing the results I'm looking for. I'm new to this so I might be missing something.

Here's what the dataset looks like:  https://ibb.co/jWD48W6

I want to find association rules among the items. Selecting the column Item does obviously not yield the result I'm looking for. If there's an alternative way to make the data suitable for the Association Rules widget I'll gladly that technique instead!

Comment: I see. What you are looking for is called a Pivot Table, where rows would be transaction IDs, columns items and values would be transaction values. The only problem is Pivot Table outputs these columns as continuous instead of discrete, making it difficult to work with Associate add-on.